# C++ HW Help using stack

Tags: c++

I am a little stuck on how to use the stack and why I would even use stack in the code I am writing. The assingment says to write a program that checks if the user input is well-Iformed or not. It is a simple prgram that has three different selections the use can choose from. 1. basic brackets () 2. standard brackets ()[]{} and 3. User-definded brackets. The only thing the main program is suppose to do is to check if the users input is well-formed or not and display only that message on the screen.

I have a StackLS.cpp and a Stack.h file I am using along with my main.cpp. I will paste a sample code below from each.

**StackLS.h**

```
typedef int elemType; // flexible data type

class StackLS
{
 private:
// inner class node

class Node
{
public:
    elemType data; // data portion
    Node *next; // link to the seccessor
}; // end Node

// data members
Node *topItem; // pointer to the top element of this stack

// utilities

       public:
// constructors
StackLS(void); // default constructor
StackLS(const StackLS& aStack); // copy constructor

// observers
bool isEmpty(void) const;
// returns true if this stack is empty
//         false otherwise

bool isFull(void) const;
// returns true if this stack is full
//         false otherwise

elemType top(void) const;
// precondition: this stack is not empty
// returns top element in this stack

// transformers
void push(const elemType& item);
// precondition: this stack is not full
// adds item to this stack

void pop(void);
// removes top element from this stack if exist
// remains empty otherwise

void makeEmpty(void);
// makes this stack empty

// destructor
~StackLS(void);
}; // end StackLS
```

**StackLS.cpp**

```
     // constructors
      StackLS::StackLS(void)
     // default constructor
     {
topItem = 0;
      } // end default constructor

        StackLS::StackLS(const StackLS& aStack)
     // copy constructor
       {
       } // end copy constructor

      // observers
       bool StackLS::isEmpty(void) const
       // returns true if this stack is empty
       //         false otherwise
        {
  return topItem == 0;
         } // end isEmpty

         bool StackLS::isFull(void) const
       // returns true if this stack is full
       //         false otherwise
        {
return false;
         } // end isFull

         elemType StackLS::top(void) const
      // precondition: this stack is not empty
       // returns top element in this stack
        {
// return (*topItem).data;
return topItem->data;
      } // end top

       // transformers
        void StackLS::push(const elemType& item)
       // precondition: this stack is not full
            // adds item to this stack
           {
Node *newNode = new Node;
newNode->data = item;
newNode->next = topItem;
topItem = newNode;
       } // end push

       void StackLS::pop(void)
       // removes top element from this stack if exist
       // remains empty otherwise
       {
if (topItem != 0)
{
    Node *temp = topItem;
    topItem = topItem->next;
    delete temp;
}
      } // end pop

      void StackLS::makeEmpty(void)
       // makes this stack empty
        {
    while (topItem != 0)
{
    Node *temp = topItem;
    topItem = topItem->next;
    delete temp;
    }
        } // end makeEmpty

         // destructor
          StackLS::~StackLS(void)
         {
//while (!isEmpty())
//  pop();
while (topItem != 0)
{
    Node *temp = topItem;
    topItem = topItem->next;
    delete temp;
}
      } // end destructor
```

Here is the main.cpp that I have so far.
**main.cpp**

```
      #include <iostream>
      #include <string>
      #include "StackLS.h"
      using namespace std;

         do {

      int main()
       {
char answer;
char n;
StackLS stack;

cout << " ********** MENU ********** " << endl;
cout << " 1. Basic Brackets () " << endl;
cout << " 2. Standard Brackets ()[]{} " << endl;
cout << " 3. User-Defined brackets " << endl;
cout << " Please enter your choice: " << endl;

switch (choice){
case 1: 
    cout << "Current Setting: () " << endl;
    cout << "Enter your expression followed by a ; : " << endl;
    do {

    cin >> answer;
        while (answer != ;)
    }


          } // end main

        }
while (choice != 'n' || 'N')
```

Again I am wondering how I would use the stack I have shown you in this program (main.cpp). I am a little confused on why I would use stack and why. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. The main.cpp may not be right but again I am learning and that is why I am here to learn more. Thanks

Comment: When someone says "the stack", they usually mean "the call stack".  What you have is *a* stack data structure, but it is not *the* stack.

Answer (score 1):

When you see an opening brace, you push it onto the stack.  When you see a closing brace, you make sure it is the counterpart of the brace on top of the stack, then pop it off.  When your input is done, you make sure the stack is empty.

Comment: Okay. That helps a little. I'm not sure how to do that though. How I would put into code if it's opening brace then push and closing make sure it is counterpart to opening brace. Any advice on that?

Comment: Just loop through the input one character at a time and compare against the different kinds of braces.

Comment: I do have a loop to do one character at a time. I'm lost how I use the stack in the main.cpp though. How I use the methods declared in each.

Comment: sorry. Would it be something like if (answer == '(' ) then push onto stack? how would I push it onto stack if so?

Comment: `stack.push('(');`  You probably want to change your `elemType` to `char` instead of `int` at the top of your header file.  Looking at the top would be `if (stack.top() == '(')`.

Comment: So would case 1 look something like this? `case 1: 
  cout << "Current Setting: () " << endl;
  cout << "Enter your expression followed by a ; : " << endl;
  do {

  cin >> answer;
   
  
  if (answer = '(')
   stack.push( '(' );
  else 
   if (stack.top() == '(')
   
  }
  while (answer != ';');`